# connect from one workstation to another that is on a different IP range?

Tags: routing, nat

This is my setup below. Router A is the main router. I am on workstation 1.100 (that gets an IP from Router A via DHCP).

Router B has an ip with 10.1 at the end but gets the "internet or WAN" via DHCP from router A. Workstation with 10.101 has a static IP and connects to Router B as its Gateway.

[image]

I want to be able to access Workstation that ends in 10.101 from workstation that ends in 1.100. How can I configure the routers to allow this? They both run DD-WRT if it helps.

Comment: Does router B need to be a router?  Could you use a switch instead so both are on the same network? (192.168.1.x)

Comment: I don't @ the moment have an extra switch, unless I can dumb down the router so it becomes a switch? That would be ideal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per your comment, I'd suggest you replace router B with a switch.  Until then, you can disable routing on B so that it behaves like a switch by doing the following:

1. On B, disable DHCP and assign it an IP address in the 192.168.1.x range outside the scope that is defined in router A.  You can can probably use 192.168.1.254
2. On B, unplug the cable (that goes to A) from the WAN port and plug it into a LAN port.
3. Either assign computer B an IP address in the 192.168.1.x range or enable DHCP so that it leases an IP from router A.

After that, your two computers will be on the same network which will allow you to setup shares.  I'm assuming the Internet is plugged into the WAN of router A.  If so, this will make sure you are not double-NATing any computer that is plugged into B.

Comment: thank you both. @pooter03's answer fit the bill exactly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup a static route in both routers, so they can comunicate properly. Following your example:

**Router A:** You configure the port connected to Router B, putting the network IP address, gateway (in this case, the IP address of router B), mask and so on..

**Router B:** You configure the port connected to Router A, putting the network IP address, gateway (in this case, the IP address of router A), mask and so on..

You can read more of this type of configuration here:
http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Linking_Subnets_with_Static_Routes